# Idiomatic haskell using takewhile and iterate

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn Haskell by working my way through [the CIS 194 course at the *University of Pennsylvania*](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures.html) course online. In one of the exercises the student is supposed to re-write a function:

```
fun1 :: [Integer] -> Integer
fun1 [] = 1
fun1 (x:xs)
  | even x = (x - 2) * fun1 xs
  | otherwise = fun1 xs
```

Into a more 'idiomatic' haskell. I rewrote the function as

```
fun1 :: [Integer] -> Integer
fun1 xs =
  let spl = partition even xs
  in foldl (*) 1 ((map (subtract 2) (fst spl)) ++ snd spl)
```

which seems... lispy. It translates almost character for character into how I would write it in clojure. In the assignment it gives the hint to use `takeWhile` and `iterate` from Prelude to rewrite the function. While I understand superficially what those functions do, it was not immediately obvious to me how to rewrite that function to use them. How may this be rewritten using `takeWhile` and `iterate`?

Comment: There is no obvious, natural way to write this function with `takeWhile` and `iterate` (in my mind, at least). If anything, this is an exercise in mental gymnastics. Also note your 2nd function is not the same of the first - the first ignore odd values, and the second does not.

Comment: @user2407038 yeah, I misunderstood the nature of the exercise, hence my use of partition and concatenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually has not much to do with `takeWhile`. You simply calculate the product here of `x-2` for every *even* number `x` in the given list. Indeed:

```
fun1 :: [Integer] -> Integer
fun1 [] = 1 -- the product of an empty list is 1
fun1 (x:xs)
  -- if the number is even, we multiply (x-2) with the remaining part
  | even x = (x - 2) * fun1 xs
  -- if the number is odd, we ignore x and return the fun1 of the tail
  | otherwise = fun1 xs
```

So we can write it as:

```
fun1 :: Integral i => [i] -> i
fun1 = product . map (subtract 2) . filter even
```

In case you cannot use `product`, you can use - like you did in the question - use:

```
fun1 :: Integral i => [i] -> i
fun1 = foldl (*) 1 . map (subtract 2) . filter even
```

This is what we call a *pointfree* version: there are no parameters in the head of `fun1` or any lambda expressions. So we do not think in terms of values, but more in terms of functions.

For a list `[1,3,4]`, this generates:

```
Prelude> (foldl (*) 1 . map (subtract 2) . filter even) [1,3,4]
2
```